# White / gray screen on monitor when off ( plus buzzing )

Tags: display, hardware-failure

So I picked up a monitor in the department "free bin" and it works great except for two things:

1. When it's off, it displays this white/gray screen -- which I suppose could be the default setting, but I doubt it (the brand is Princeton).
2. It also buzzes or hisses, sort of sounds like a motherboard working hard. Interestingly, when the monitor is off (and the screen is white), the buzzing gets louder than it is when the monitor is on.

I opened it up looking for a swelled capacitor (which is what google said I ought to do), but didn't see any. To be fair, I'm also not 100% sure what to look for other than a cracked top, and this could also be completely off-base. I've connected it to two different computers, and am fairly confident the problem is with the monitor and not a graphics card or anything as these problems exist when it isn't connected to any machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Put it on a switched outlet or power strip. If it works well when *on*, just shut the power when the PC is off. There are power-strips that sense the current draw of a PC and that shut *all* peripherals off to reduce parasitic power drain and chance of damage due to power surge. One example is at http://www.amazon.com/Take-Charge-Smart-Power-Strip/dp/B005DTBCD2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though that's maybe not my ideal solution.